# Mule : how do I deploy multiple Mule projects together as one?

Tags: maven, deployment, mule

I'd like to keep Mule Projects small for the sake of simplicity. This means that I'd only like a single Mule project to hold flows which are related.

However, when deploying I'd like to bundle all projects and deploy them together as one. Is there a good way to do this using Maven which will result in a single Mule deployable file which to Mule looks like a single project?

Comment: So, you have several Maven projects building your Mule applications?

Comment: Well, I'd like to split up Mule applications on several projects in order to have a single project to only hold flows that are conceptually related. However, I'd like to deploy these projects together as a single deployment.

Comment: Would it work to have separate maven modules and use a separate module that assembly all your projects in a single one?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your mule-deploy.properties file is the one responsible for holding the list of flows which should be executed or deployed.
It is generated automatically, when you first create a project. It automatically gets populated as flows are added.
It is located at src->main->app.
Try to deploy the project on mule-standalone and it will deploy all the flows as one.